# Google Tag Manager breaks download attribute on a tag

Tags: anchor, google-tag-manager

We are having an issue where the file is not auto-populated on Save-as dialog.

Below tag is getting generated by JSONToCsvService(library) and appended to body tag.

Analytics Report

When we click on this element it should popup a Save -as dialog in same window and pre populate the file name ( in above case Sample.csv)

[image]

when there is no Google Tag Manager then file name is shown properly in Save-as dialog. When Google Tag manager is enabled file get downloaded but file name is not auto populated.

Answer (score 7):

Our link element looked like this.

```html
<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%20Messages%20Sent" download="Analytics_Summary.csv">Download File</a>
```

Adding target attribute to this fixed the issue.

```html
<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%20Messages%20Sent" download="Analytics_Summary.csv" target="_blank">Download File</a>
```