# what causes the browser to completely ignore the download attribute

Tags: html

I thought i do understand the way a[download] is supposed to work:
As long as the link looks "safe" and is in the same origin as the page, where the link is rendered, the browser should display a save-as dialog insteadof opening the linked resource in the browser.

But what else can disable the behaviour? In one of my customers websites, i removed a bloated controller-action that would send a http-header to enforce the save-as dialog in favor of the a[download] variant.

But no browser will open the dialog, everytime i click the link, the content gets rendered in the browser (firefox and chrome).

I even tried simplified static examples but no success...

```html
<a download="test.css" href="/static/css/app.css">download</a>
<a download="test.pdf" href="/assets/file.pdf">download</a>
```

I dont get it... the behaviour is the same at other pcs

My webserver does not send any suspicious headers for the linked files, example for a pdf:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 03 Mar 2021 12:32:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Sep 2020 14:38:03 GMT
ETag: "9020cf-5b0609d2579f4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 9445583
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Expires: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 12:32:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Of course i can simply revert my changes and forget about it but i absolutely NEED TO know the reasons :)

**UPDATE**

So, this has to be related to google-tag-manager. As soon as i remove the gtm implementation, the download attribute is respected.

When inspecting the browser logs after clicking the link, i can see some warnings (sorry for the german text, i am inserting some translation below):

```
Einige Cookies verwenden das empfohlene "SameSite"-Attribut inkorrekt.

Das Cookie "_ga" wird in Zukunft bald abgelehnt werden, da es für das Attribut "SameSite" entweder "None" oder einen ungültigen Wert angibt, ohne das "secure"-Attribut zu verwenden. Weitere Informationen zum "SameSite"-Attribut finden Sie unter https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite.

6 more messages of this type
```

this tells me, that analytics adds some cookie with "SameSite" set to "None" without using the "secure" attribute.

So it seems, that the cookie added by analytics/gtm compromises the whole http request and firefox (and even chromium) will not respect the download-attribute for security reasons.

Or some tracking messes things up. I dont know - but i am goint to dig into this and update/close this question.

Comment: That probably happens because browsers prefer showing PDFs instead of downloading them.

Comment: Which browser did you use ? I've try on one of my live projet on Chrome without any problems `<a href="path/to/the/file.pdf" download="test.pdf">The pdf</a>`.

Comment: Firefox on Ubuntu, Chromium on Ubuntu and i know the problem exists for Firefox on Windows as well.

Comment: The workaround posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62828321/google-tag-manager-breaks-download-attribute-on-a-tag) works for me.